# How to do python itertools.combinations

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find out the list of possible products from all supplier combinations.
Finding out either one in the combinations can produce the products

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

Column = {'ID':['1','2','3','4','5'],'Supplier 1':['B','B','A','B','B'],'Supplier 2':['A','NaN','B','NaN','A']}
df=pd.DataFrame(Column)
df

# Define all Supplier Columns
cols = [c for c in df.columns if "Supplier" in c]
# get unique suppliers
suppl = np.unique(np.concatenate([df[c].dropna() for c in cols]))
result = []
for sn in range(len(suppl)):
# generate combinations of suppliers
for combi in itertools.combinations(suppl, sn+1):
result.append({combi:......
```

From

```
ID  Supplier 1  Supplier 2
1    B          A
2    B          NaN
3    A          B
4    B          NaN
5    B          A
```

Desire(Either one of the supplier can produce):

```
Supplier    ID
A           1,3,5
B           1,2,3,4,5
A,B         1,2,3,4,5
```

NEW CODE:

```
from itertools import combinations, chain
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = {'ID':['1','2','3','4','5'],'Supplier 1':['B','B','A','B','B'],'Supplier 2':['A',np.nan,'B',np.nan,'A']}
df=pd.DataFrame(Column)
from itertools import combinations, chain

g1 = df.groupby(['Supplier 1'])['ID'].apply(list)
g2 = df.groupby(['Supplier 2'])['ID'].apply(list)

res = (g1 + g2).to_dict()
res = [[','.join(comb), ','.join(sorted(set(chain.from_iterable([res[k] for k in comb]))))]
       for x in range(1, len(res) + 1) for comb in combinations(res.keys(), x)]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=['Supplier', 'ID'])
print(df2)
```

Comment: `Supplier 2` have `C` in your dictionary but your example not showing `C`

Comment: @deadshot, my mistake. There are only A and B as the Table. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an efficient solution but this will work

```
from itertools import combinations, chain

g1 = df.groupby(['Supplier 1'])['ID'].apply(list)
g2 = df.groupby(['Supplier 2'])['ID'].apply(list)

res = (g1 + g2).to_dict()
res = [[','.join(comb), ','.join(sorted(set(chain.from_iterable([res[k] for k in comb]))))]
       for x in range(1, len(res) + 1) for comb in combinations(res.keys(), x)]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=['Supplier', 'ID'])
print(df2)
```

**Output:**

```
  Supplier         ID
0        A      1,3,5
1        B  1,2,3,4,5
2      A,B  1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: Thanks @deadshot, but it pop up an error . Does it happen to you?

`---> 12        for x in range(1, len(res) + 1) for comb in combinations(res.keys(), x)]
  

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`

Comment: No I didn't get any error. Replace 'NaN' with np.nan

Comment: It still showing the error.
I have paste the full code on it. Is it possible you could help take a look. Many thanks.

Comment: Remove the quotes around np.nan

Comment: The Same error. I just completely copy your code without modifying. Don't know what's happening